# How do I get a list of latitudes/longitudes an exact distance from a point on the globe?

Tags: python, coordinates, distance

I have a point in (latitude, longitude), say (10,30), and I'm trying to create a list of N coordinates in a circle that are exactly D nautical miles away. Basically, I'm looking to create a ring of N coordinates around a central point with a certain radius D.

I am currently using geopy and may have limited access to other packages. My brute force method was to create a grid of coordinates and just save the ones within (D-1.5 < X < D+1.5) nautical miles away, but that gives me a very jagged circle and is time intensive.

How can I quickly and accurately create this list of N (latitude, longitude) coordinates in a ring (of radius D) around my central point?

Comment: Could you please create a minimal, complete and verifiable example? It would be nice to see a piece of code that you've tried so that one will be able to improve it

Comment: Frankly, I don't know where to begin to get a real answer to this question. My "brute force method" is just so I have something temporary to look at when I later plot it. I just took a grid of latitudes and longitudes, calculated the distance from each gridpoint to the central point using geopy's distance.distance function, and if it with within 1.5 miles of my radius (so 98.5 to 101.5 nautical miles of the central point if radius = 100), I saved that (latitude,longitude) point to a new list. It takes several minutes to run if I don't want a super jagged circle.

Comment: [HERE](http://www.edwilliams.org/avform.htm) are some formulae that are applicable. Specifically, the formula for a new lat,lon based on a range+bearing from an existing lat,lon. Simply loop 360ª around the first lat, lon. Good luck!